# When laptop switches on, the led lights up but nothing on screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, cpu, motherboard

My laptop is a Samsung n150 plus and it runs windows 7 starter with 2gb ram and Intel atom processor with 1.66ghz clock rate.However, when i plugged in the charger a led lights up(which is for show charging) and also when i switch it on another led(which is to show power is on) also lights up.My power on/off switch is a toggle switch which is located on the front edge of the laptop.And also i can hear the CPU fan is also working, but the screen remains black(even it doesn't light up).

I've tried,

```
(These thing were on some other websites)

- Removing battery and unplugging the charger and hold the power button for 30 seconds.
- FN + F5
- Continuosly pressing F11
- FN + F1
- FN + F2
```

But it gave me no results.

Please tell me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can’t tell you what component of your hardware has failed.

Depending on your technical expertise, you may be able to go through a troubleshooting method that involves isolating the components and confirming what is causing the issue.

For most people in this situation, one of two things have happened. One, the RAM has worked itself loose or has developed bad connections. Two, the motherboard/CPU (often married together and not interchangeable) has failed.

The first issue with RAM is really common. Access the RAM, remove it and try re-inserting it. Sometimes using contact cleaner is necessary to help clean oxidation off of the contact points. Sometimes machines of this style will have the RAM also married to the motherboard and it will not be interchangeable.

If the computer continues to remain non-functional, chances are high the motherboard/CPU have failed. A machine of this age would not be worth trying to fix in my opinion, however you might be able to purchase a used motherboard/CPU and replace it. It would have to be very cheap to justify the repair as the laptop has almost no value.

There is no guarantee that replacing the motherboard/CPU will actually fix the problem. Only advanced troubleshooting by isolating components and swapping parts, etc. will determine the cause of the issue.